# C# Linq DeleteObject

Tags: c#, linq

My problem is that i have 2 tables one about movie datas and the other about rentals and the primary key is the movietitle from the first table and the movietitle foreign key is in the rentals table.

I would like to delete the full row from rentals when on my form user select a  movie from the listbox (data from movie table) and the full row from the rentals table becomes deleted (i am trying to delete the primary key of rentals but i get error on the second line :

> Error  13  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet.DeleteObject(movies.Rentals)' has some invalid arguments)

```
var search = (from g in db.Rentals 
              where g.Movietitle == (string)listbox1.SelectedValue 
              select g.Szigszam  // this is the primary key in the rentals table,the foreign key is the movie title)
              .First();
db.Rentals.DeleteObject(search);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

You must do like this.

```
var search = (from g in db.Rentals 
              where g.Movietitle == (string)listbox1.SelectedValue 
              select g).First();
db.Rentals.DeleteObject(search);
db.SaveChanges();
```